# System.DmlException: Update failed

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

> System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id
>   a2E4D00000056nGUAQ; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION,
>   **Campaign Quantity is less than Sum of Placements Quantity:** []: Class.MediaAllocationCampaignUtilities.updateMediaAllocationPlacementsMethod:
>   line 95, column 1

**Below is My Trigger:**

```
trigger ValidateQunat on Media_Allocation__c (before update) {

Decimal x= 0;
Decimal y= 0;
List<Id> MedIDLst = new List<Id>();
 for(Media_Allocation__c medAloc : Trigger.new)
 {
     MedIDLst.add(medAloc.Id);
 }   
List<Media_Allocation_Placement__c> plcLst = [SELECT Id,Quantity__c FROM Media_Allocation_Placement__c WHERE Media_Allocation_Campaign__c =: MedIDLst];
// List<Media_Allocation__c> MedLst = [Select id, quantity__c from Media_Allocation__c where id = 'a2E4D00000056nG'];    
 List<Media_Allocation__c> MedLst = [Select id, quantity__c from Media_Allocation__c where id =: MedIDLst];

     for(Media_Allocation__c medAloc : Trigger.new)
    {

        for(Media_Allocation_Placement__c plc : plcLst)
        {
          if(plc.Quantity__c !=NULL)
          x+= plc.Quantity__c;
          system.debug('****************'+x);
        }
        for(Media_Allocation__c Med : MedLst)
        {
            y = Med.Quantity__c;
            system.debug('$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$'+y);

        }
        try{ 
        if(y<x)
        {
         medAloc.addError('Campaign Quantity is less than Sum of Placements Quantity');
        }
        }catch(Exception e){

        //medAloc.adderror(e);
        }


    }
}
```

**Note: I want to handle that exception and populate User Understandable Error like "Campaign Quantity is less than Sum of Placements Quantity"**alone

Comment: do you want to display this message on standard layout, or custom VF page, lighting component?

Answer (score 0):

To give user friendly error message out of exception will require little bit of try catch game in your code at the place where the error is actually rising. So your trigger will look like this after proper try catch combination in the red zone.

```
trigger ValidateQunat on Media_Allocation__c(before update) {

 Decimal x = 0;
 Decimal y = 0;
 List<Id> MedIDLst = new List<Id>();

 for (Media_Allocation__c medAloc: Trigger.new) {
  MedIDLst.add(medAloc.Id);
 }

 List <Media_Allocation_Placement__c> plcLst = [SELECT Id, Quantity__c FROM Media_Allocation_Placement__c WHERE Media_Allocation_Campaign__c =: MedIDLst];
 List <Media_Allocation__c> MedLst = [Select id, quantity__c from Media_Allocation__c where id =: MedIDLst];

 for (Media_Allocation__c medAloc : Trigger.new) {

  for (Media_Allocation_Placement__c plc : plcLst) {
   if (plc.Quantity__c != NULL)
    x += plc.Quantity__c;
    system.debug('****************' + x);
  }//end 1st for

  for (Media_Allocation__c Med: MedLst) {    
    try {
       y = Med.Quantity__c;
       System.debug('$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$' + y);

       if(y < x) 
         throw new DMLException();

    } catch (DMLException e) {    
        Med.Quantity__c.addError('Campaign Quantity is less than Sum of Placements Quantity');    
    }    
  }//end 2nd for

 }//end main for

}//end trigger
```

Comment: not sure about the total solution but addError can't be added like this medAloc.plc.Quantity__c.addError see here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm.

Comment: @Avijit Chakraborty. 'Plc' was just a typo. But if we want to show error next to a field of an object. We can use it and it works.

Comment: I don't see how an error is thrown and thus the catch will never happen...